# make GDB expand the arg=... on backtrace

Tags: c++, c, debugging, gdb

When I type gdb backtrace, I get:

```
(gdb) bt 1
#0  Handler::send (this=0x2ba2b10, src=..., to=..., newMessage=true) at main.cpp:138
```

As you can see, gdb displays **src=...** and **to=...** and does not show the actual values.

How do I force gdb to exapnd the stack trace without explicitly printing the variables ?

Answer (score 5):

By default gdb prints only scalar values in backtrace. To print all values (arrays, structures, unions) set `print frame-arguments` to `all`:

```
set print frame-arguments all
```

See [documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Print-Settings.html#Print-Settings).